# Flutter - Custom back button doesn't work

Tags: flutter

I have an `alertdialog` which is supposed to return a bool depending on the user's choice, the message gets removed, but the back button isn't working!

```
 Future<bool?> showwarning(BuildContext context) async {
    showDialog<bool>(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: new Text("Alert!!"),
              content: new Text("Return To Main Page?!"),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                  child: new Text("Yes"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context, true);
                  },
                ),
                TextButton(
                  child: new Text("Nope"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context, false);
                  },
                )
              ],
            ));
  }
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build

    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          final user_decision = await showwarning(context);
          return user_decision ?? false;
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Future<bool?> showwarning(BuildContext context) async {
    return showDialog<bool>(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: new Text("Alert!!"),
              content: new Text("Return To Main Page?!"),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                  child: new Text("Yes"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context, true);
                  },
                ),
                TextButton(
                  child: new Text("Nope"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context, false);
                  },
                )
              ],
            ));
  }
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build

    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          final user_decision = await showwarning(context);
          return user_decision ?? false;
        },
```

The problem is that I wasn't returning anything from showwarning function  , hence, it was always false!